# Kafka Stream-consumer to perform multiple streaming computations on the same stream

Tags: cassandra, stream, apache-kafka

I am using `Kafka stream` to process streams of JSON Data. I want to perform two tasks.

1. Persist all data into a data store, say Cassandra.
2. Perform window based computing to identify some patterns, and also persist only the pattern of interest in another table.

Is it possible to do both these activities within the same `Kafka stream` consumer and redirect the respective output to 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can call `peek` on the KStream - it will perform operation with side-effect (write into Cassandra), and return unchanged stream on which you can perform necessary computations.

See [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html) on example of use (unfortunately there is no links to subsections).